# Dell Inspiron 15 R n series

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers, dell-inspiron, x86

I want win7 32-bit wireless driver for my laptop (dell inspiron 15R core I7 n series)
I searched at the main site but all drivers were for 64-bit only and till now no driver worked for it, I really need it, any help please.

This is link for the network controller id

[image: http://www.mediafire.com/view/0ephiah5064b41d/wireless_hd_id.PNG]

Comment: You should add the exact network device your system has.  Dell has a habit of having several cards that may go into a model.  Go to the support site, search by your service tag number and get the info from the original configuration page.

Comment: The problem that all drivers with my service tag are for 64 bit.

Comment: Yes, but if you specify what the actual device is, someone may be able to point to the manufacturer's website or other location.  Without the info, no one can search.

Comment: I hope this help http://www.mediafire.com/view/0ephiah5064b41d/wireless_hd_id.PNG

Comment: does the linked driver work for you or not?

Answer (score 3):

0x86 = Intel and 008A = Intel Centrino Wireless-N1030. Try this driver:

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=23721&lang=eng&ProdId=3311

Download the `Wireless_16.11.0_Ds32.zip`, extract the zip and point in device manager to this driver folder.